# Flutter: How to place two widgets one below another inside a column without `RenderOverflow` error?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

i have a grid view with 5 objects. Each grid will contain a photo and a button below it. The gridview will hold 3 images in a row, the photos should be Box.fit.

Please check the below code

```
class EditPortfolioScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  EditPortfolioScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditPortfolioScreenState createState() => _EditPortfolioScreenState();
}

class _EditPortfolioScreenState extends State<EditPortfolioScreen> {
  final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController titleTxtCtrl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descriptionTxtCtrl = TextEditingController();
  List<File> imageListFile = [];
  List<SellerPortfolioItemImages> imageList = [];
  final addPortfolioController = AddPortfolioController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as PortfolioAndImages;

    titleTxtCtrl =
        TextEditingController(text: screenArgs.sellerPortfolioItem.title);
    descriptionTxtCtrl =
        TextEditingController(text: screenArgs.sellerPortfolioItem.description);
    imageList = screenArgs.imageList;

    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: Colors.black, //change your color here
              ),
              title: Text("My Portfolio"),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
              late final maxHeight;
              if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
                maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
              } else {
                maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight * 2;
              }
              return Form(
                key: formkey,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        _buildPhotoSection(),
                        SizedBox(height: 16),
                        // Many other widgets are here, removed them to make a minimal code
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            })));
  }

  Widget _buildPhotoSection() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text("Portfolio Photos", style: subtitle1Style),
        SizedBox(height: 8),
        GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
            ),
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Card(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          imageUrl: imageList[index].imageURL == ""
                              ? "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/no-image-icon-6.png"
                              : imageList[index].imageURL,
                          placeholder: (context, url) =>
                              CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                              Icon(Icons.error),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      )),
                  TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Change"))
                ],
              );
            })
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The output is as below

[image]

You can see that i am having `Render overflow` issues. Now if I wrap the `card` with `Expanded` I get the below output.

[image]

This is not what I need either, the photos are very compact. My requirement is something like below but with the button at the bottom of each image.

[image]

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, Instead of the `column` you can use `Wrap`.

```
Widget _buildPhotoSection() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text("Portfolio Photos"),
        SizedBox(height: 8),
        GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
            ),
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Wrap(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 20),
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/profile.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(child: TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Change"))),
                ],
              );
            })
      ],
    );
  }
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I posted this question because i wanted to have the bottom button. I know how to do it without the button.

Comment: do you want place `change`  button

Comment: Yes, That is right.

Comment: under every image ?? give me some moment I will fix it?

Comment: That's right. Yes.

Comment: @PeakGen please check my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You should check with `CachedNetworkImage` and with both portait and landscape images.